# Copy worksheet from one workbook (not opened) to opened workbook

Tags: excel, copy, vba

Is it possible to copy a worksheet from a workbook without opening it and pasting it to the opened workbook with no default file location ? The worksheet that I am trying to copy from contains a total of 30 worksheets. I have tried using file dialog to open but sometimes it would hang the excel. Is there any way that won't hang the excel and do what I want? Thank you in advance.

```
Dim FileToOpen As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Excel File to Open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.(*.xlsx),xlsx")
If VarType(FileToOpen) = vbBoolean Then
MsgBox "No file selected", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
Exit Sub
End If
Debug.Assert VarType(FileToOpen) = vbString
With Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
.Worksheets(22).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("A1")
.Close
End With
```

Comment: In principle, it isn't possible to access anything from a digital file without opening it. However, it is possible to open it in such a way that the user never realises that something is opened, copied and closed. If you know the exact location of the file you wish to access you can let the code open it without user interference. Else, if you don't know the location, or the name, the FileOpen dialog is the way to go. Why don't you post your code and let's see why your Excel crsashes?

Comment: hi i edited and added the code as above

Comment: So, you say that Excel just hangs. No error message? No debug highlight? Perhaps it's just a matter of Windows being too fast for Excel, closing the file before the copying is finished. In that case try to do something before you close the source file, perhaps `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. Try to name both the source and the target workbooks. Name both the source and the target worksheets - all not strictly necessary but suitable to let VBA know who is the boss.

Comment: I thought that it hangs because there is 30 worksheets in that workbook. There is no error message or debug highlight.  I can try that.

Comment: Don't know. Size of the workbook might make a difference. I was thinking more of the size of the copied data. Doesn't matter which, or both. Please try the suggestions I made.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub test()
 Dim app As New Excel.Application
 Dim fileName As String, copyFrom As Workbook
 app.Visible = False
 fileName = app.GetOpenFilename()

 Set copyFrom = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
  MsgBox copyFrom.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

this should fit what you want to achieve

Comment: edit the codes accordingly to fit your needs. this is just a skeleton